# Как получить картинку из другого поста вордпресс

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Всем здрасте.
Есть новая задачка, и снова со звездочкой.
Есть ссылка вида "[https://сайт.ру/категория/#5555](https://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/#5555)"
Нужно из этой ссылки вытащить все, что после #. Сделать это не проблема, но проблема в том, что сделать это средствами php нельзя, но можно JS. Вытащенные цифры пишутся в переменную (Это ID поста вордпресс) и по ней из этого поста нужно получить картинку.
Как изящнее это сделать, передать переменную AJAX-ом в php скрипт или прямо внутри js скрипта выполнить php?

Answer (score 0):

Решилось все довольно просто - символ решетки в ссылке заменил на символ вопросительного знака, что позволило получить ID.
Может кому пригодится

```
function curPageName() 
{
return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}
$img_hash = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть возможность менять вид ссылки, то возможно стоит передавать id `GET` запросом. И получать картинку как-то так:

```
// Пример адреса  
// $url = 'http://your.site/category/?id_post=5555'

$postId = $_GET['id_post']; // Получаем ID поста - 5555
$imgUrl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postId); // Получаем ссылку на основное изображение поста
```

А получить все после # на php можно следующим образом:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
```